# return object with property value

Tags: javascript

I have the following data:

```
  var data = { 
    someData : [
      {
        title: "something",
        color: "red",
        moreInfo : [
          {
            title: "something else",
            color: "orange",
            moreInfo : [
              {
                title: "something more",
                color: "green",
                moreInfo : [
                  {
                    title: "another title",
                    color: "yellow"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            title: "blah blah",
            color: "blue"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "something cool",
        color: "black"
      }
    ]
  };
```

I want to run a function to return the object with the property that matches a certain value.
Currently I have this:

```
  var result = data.filter(obj => {
    return obj.title === "something more";
  });
```

I want the function to be able to iterate through every object and nested object and return the object with that value. 
So in this case I would like for it to return:

```
{
  title: "something more",
  color: "green",
  moreInfo: [
    {
     title: "another title",
     color: "yellow"
    }
 ]
}
```

If someone could please help me with this. It seems simple enough but I have spent way too much time on this.Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to implement a solution using recursion?

Comment: @fubar thanks for responding. I have but I'm having trouble returning the object if it is nested.

Comment: There is an error in your code. The error is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer! `somedata = []` it should be `somedata : []`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter array recursively using below-mentioned function:

```
  var filter = (array) => {
    array.filter(obj => {
     if(obj.title === "something more"){
     return obj     
   }
    if(obj.moreInfo){
     filter(obj.moreInfo)
    }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive function like this:

```js
function dig(obj, func){
  let v;
  if(obj instanceof Array){
    for(let i=0,l=obj.length; i<l; i++){
      v = obj[i];
      if(typeof v === 'object'){
        dig(v, func);
      }
      else{
        func(v, i, obj);
      }
    }
  }
  else{
    for(let i in obj){
      v = obj[i];
      if(typeof v === 'object'){
        dig(v, func);
      }
      else{
        func(v, i, obj);
      }
    }
  }
}
// I don't like your sytax - but didn't fix it
var data = { 
    someData: [
      {
        title: "something",
        color: "red",
        moreInfo: [
          {
            title: "something else",
            color: "orange",
            moreInfo: [
              {
                title: "something more",
                color: "green",
                moreInfo: [
                  {
                    title: "another title",
                    color: "yellow"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            title: "blah blah",
            color: "blue"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        title: "something cool",
        color: "black"
      }
    ]
  };
function getObjByTitle(object, title){
  let obj = false;
  dig(object, (v, k, o)=>{
    if(k === 'title' && v === title){
      obj = o;
    }
  });
  return obj;
}
console.log(getObjByTitle(data, 'something more'));
```